# how do update the options in an html form based on what year it is?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date, html-select

i'm trying to set up a webpage with a form that asks for soemone to fill in a year with a drop down, but i also want it to change based on what year it is, ie: it is now 2014 so i want to show 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018. in 2015 it would show 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019.

i have the following html code that i use for the form

```
<td valign="top">
<select name="month" id="month">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option> 
</select>
<select name="day" id="day">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="year" id="year">
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>


        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="Date" value="firm" id="Date0" />
          firm</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="Date" value="flexible" id="Date1" />
          flexible</label>
     </td>`
```

and i was thinking to use javascript to update it with something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var selOptions = [
                ['2014','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018'],
                ['2015','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019'],
                ['2016','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020'],
                ['2017','2017','2018','2019','2020','2021'],
                ['2018','2018','2019','2020','2021','2022'],
                ['2019','2019','2020','2021','2022','2023'],
                ['2020','2020','2021','2022','2023','2024'],
                ['2021','2021','2022','2023','2024','2025']
            ];
            function setSel2Options(obj){
                oSel2.options.length = 0;
                if(obj.selectedIndex == 0){return;}
                for(i=0; i < selOptions.length; i++){
                    if(obj.value == selOptions[i][0]){
                        oSel2.options[oSel2.options.length] = new Option('Select a year','',false,false);
                        for(j=1; j < selOptions[i].length; j++){  
                            oSel2.options[oSel2.options.length] = new Option(selOptions[i][j],selOptions[i][j],false,false);
                        }
                        i = selOptions.length;
                    }
                }
            }
            window.onload=function(){
                oSel1 = document.getElementById('sel1');
                oSel2 = document.getElementById('sel2');
                oSel1.options[oSel1.options.length] = new Option('Select an option','',false,false);
                for(i=0; i < selOptions.length; i++){
                    oSel1.options[oSel1.options.length] = new Option(selOptions[i][0],selOptions[i][0], false,false);
                }
                oSel1.onchange=function(){setSel2Options(this);}
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="sel1"></select>
        <select id="sel2"></select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this actually possible?